# Where does English need a lot more effort to say the same thing than another language?

Tags: english

There are a few hunter gatherer languages like Pirahã that basically only have words for the numbers 'one' and 'two'. Sometimes speakers of those languages can say four by saying 'two-two' or maybe six with 'two-two-two'. That however takes effort.

Are there cases where the English language has similar problems of mapping semantic distinctions that do exist in other languages and that aren't fixed simply by borrowing a few words?

Are there cases where other languages are simply much more efficient to speak about a subject matter?

Comment: Free as in free beer and as in freedom comes to mind...

Comment: Piraha doesn't have terms for "one" and "two". It has terms for "few" and "many" (roughly). It does not have a way to combine these terms to convey "four". It may be in the process of adopting the Portuguese number system but until then it is completely without numeracy, which is one of its most fascinating aspects. Other languages do have systems similar to what you describe though.

Comment: The answer to both of your questions is yes. Some cultures have concepts which are foreign and confusing to Anglo culture and vice versa.

Comment: If you want a concrete simple example, English is very clumsy at expressing reflexive verbs with an indirect object. Some languages (say Japanese for an extreme example, but also most languages with clitic reflexive pronouns) can do this much more elegantly.

Comment: You'd need to define "efficiency" to get a good answer. ¿Less number of syllables to say the same? Less number of words? Less complexity in the resulting phrases? In Computer Science there's this concept "Turing equivalence" which says most programming languages are functionally equivalent: every program written in one can be re-written in another, save the features of one emphasize a specific coding style and may simplify developing in a specific domain. Likewise with human languages: they all can say mostly the same

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your question is that it is built on the assumption that English is somehow the default, a natural language, from which other languages diverge. That is absolutely not the case. English is just as exotic to other languages as other languages are to it.

In fact, "mapping semantic distinctions" is going to bring up all sorts of mismatches for any given pair of languages (even fairly closely related ones). The vast majority of these will concern the lexical labelling of categories. Which means that they cannot be easily resolved by lexical borrowing because they concern conceptualisation. For instance, there's no easy way to map the different ways of saying bread between English and Czech. The English category is more general and it causes troubles for Czech speakers of English because they expect a separate words for their fine grained categories. See this list of Czech words that describe something not easy to express in English: http://www.oocities.org/athens/forum/7953/word.html

Prepositions are also going to be hard to map well. For instance, in English you have to conceptualise tree as a container to say, someone is sitting 'in a tree' whereas a language like Czech says 'on the tree'. So you can see, it's a mutual mapping issue.

However, there are also many grammatical distinctions in English that will be difficult for speakers of other languages. They might have to do with definiteness (articles) and the complex system of tenses. For instance, there's no easy way to say in Czech (and many other languages) 'I will have been cooking for 2 hours by the time you arrive.' without significant circumlocution. Conversely, Czech's aspectual system makes it easy to distinguished someone was 'shot and killed' and 'shot and not killed' without ever leaving ambiguity, whereas English always has to specify the outcome or leave it ambiguous.

The list is endless. The semantics of all languages maps onto other languages only approximately once you get out of the sterilised world of logical semantics into the world of real language use.

Comment: English isn't my native language, so I don't think I believe that English is some kind of universal default. However in practice I never found a case where I wished to switch to my native German because English is inherently unable to express what I want to say in a reasonable manner. As far as bread goes, English does a good job of burrowing a French word like baguette. I see no reason why the same shoulding work with Czech forms of bread. 

Saying that Czech forces you to specify an outcome in the shot and killed case, makes Czech less expressive not more.

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by reasonable. No two languages are a prefect match but generally they are equally expressive. But bilingual speakers often do switch between the two languages to make up for the difference. There is no measure of expressiveness so the differences are often a matter of convenience

Comment: Are you honestly claiming Pirahã is equally expressive as English when it comes to talking about numbers and math?

Comment: This is a bit of an extreme case but Pirahã gets on fine without talking about quantity and when the need arises it makes do with borrowing. You couldn't just go and write a math theorem in Pirahã. But that's not a question of linguistic expressiveness but rather effectiveness or facility in a particular context. Think about what sort of historical development Pirahã would have to go through to get to that stage and you'll find that it has all the right building blocks. Remember relatively few of 5000 languages have the vocabulary to do maths of any complexity. But math is a very special case

Comment: You can't simply fix math by borrowing words. You need syntax in addition to borrowing words. My whole question is about whether there are cases where English fails just in the same way that Piraha fails at math.

Comment: That's why math is not a good example. Pirahã didn't "fail at math", it doesn't have a way too express the concept of counting. Language doesn't need any other syntax than coordination for that. The math you seem to be talking about is its own metalanguage. It could even be argued it's not part of English but translated into English. A parallel could be the complex system of character-based puns in Mandarin.

Comment: @Christian: If you are a native German, how would you translate "Doch!" in English with a reasonably short expression?

Answer (score 0):

You ask

> Are there cases where other languages are simply much more efficient to speak about a subject matter?

and I read among the line of your question

> Do other languages have better grained vocabulary to be more efficient?

However, even *poorer* vocabulary can give your language more efficiency in expressing an idea.

Consider *genderless languages*, such as Finnish or Hungarian. They do not have different word for *he* and *she*, but one single pronoun only which means either of it. So in these languages you are much more efficient if you want to express

> *He/she* is coming from the left.

So *missing* vocabulary paradoxically *increases* your expressing efficiency. While in English you have to find totally artificial mechanism, like using plural (*they*), in Finnish you just use the very natural way.